# Notifications of iPhone to PC

Tags: windows, iphone-app

Is there any app for Windows that can receive push notifications of an iPhone? (calls, SMS, etc.).

I really need one because almost all of the time my iPhone isn’t with me (in another room charging or it’s on silent mode).

My iPhone isn't jailbroken - and I don't want to do so.

Comment: I know the opposite is possible without jailbreaking your iDevice, but I haven't yet found something that does what you want without jailbreaking... I'm afraid this might be impossible.

Comment: "app on PC": Which OS?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention it, on Windows OS.

Comment: I don't think there's already an app for that but Apple provides a way for Bluetooth devices to [receive notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html), so it's definitely possible to create an app that will make the computer appear as a Bluetooth smartwatch (or similar) to the iPhone and thus receive notifications without jaiblreaking.

Answer (score 3):

You can jailbreak your iPhone (AFAIK impossible without to get all notifications), then use the iPhone app [GrowlNotifier](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/11/03/growlnotifier/):

- free
- iOS 5 for higher
- available on the Mac or Windows.

A Growl client for Windows: http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/about.aspx (free).

Comment: Actually i know about this app but, im looking for one without Jailbreaking my iPhone ><

Comment: Which won't be possible. AFAIK, Apple doesn't allow 'normal' apps to access core system features like notifications in the way you want. Still waiting for someone to prove me wrong, but I'm afraid that won't happen.